# How to open/trigger a view controller with Siri?

Tags: ios, swift, sirikit

I'm studying SiriKit and I have a big problem. I build an app and sometimes he works, sometimes he doesn't works. I want open a specific controller without say "Start apple exercise" or something like that. I user workout because it's the most simple and I wanna know if I can only say "Open profile via MyApp". Is that possible?

Here is my code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    guard let intent = userActivity.interaction?.intent as? INStartWorkoutIntent else {
        print("AppDelegate: Start Workout Intent - FALSE")
        return false
    }
    print("AppDelegate: Start Workout Intent - TRUE")
    print("INTENT: ", intent)

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    guard let spokenPhrase = intent.workoutName?.spokenPhrase else {
        return false
    }

    switch spokenPhrase {
    case "test":
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "firstVC")

        self.window?.rootViewController = vc
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()


    case "apple":
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondVC")

        self.window?.rootViewController = vc
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    default:
        break
    }

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not possible. `SiriKit` can only be used in really specific scenarios. Due to the fact that `Siri` works with natural language processing, it needs to "listen to" some specific words in a text to be able to decode those into `Swift` objects. With each `Intent` there are some specific keywords that need to be said, otherwise `Siri` won't recognise the user input as a specific `Intent`.

Even you would "hack" your app into doing something completely irrelevant to workouts and opening it from `Siri` using workout intents, your app would most probably get rejected from the `AppStore`.